# Ajv library: Accessing keys in the nested schema validation javascript

Tags: javascript, ajv

I'm working on the use case where I need to validate the schema using `ajv` lib of the provided data which can be nested.

Now the problem is, Schema could change based on the value of a particular variable, which is not in the scope where this check is to be done.

how do I achieve it through ajv.

I tried using `if-else` & `data & const` but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've recently encountered similar use case with `ajv` validator.
By looking at your issue I believe you need to access some other scope of the actual object passed for validation, In my case it was lying in the root of the object.

So I used the `validate` function in ajv's [User Defined Keyword](https://ajv.js.org/keywords.html#define-keyword-with-validate-function) section, which in turn is giving me the whole object from top level in the first index of arguments itself, that way I accessed my dependent key in `validate` function and used it in my ajv `IF:` condition, eg

```
ajv.addKeyword({
  keyword: "isRegular",
  validate: (...test) =>  {
    const test1 = test[1]
    return test1.dependentKeyFromRootOfObject === "REGULAR"
  },
})
```

and used the then created keyword `isRegular` in the nested object's `IF:` condition like

```
  if: { isRegular: true },
  then: {
    properties: {
      rcType: { type: "string" },
      date: { type: "string" },
    },
    required: ["rcType", "date"],
    additionalProperties: false,
  },
  else: {
    properties: {
      rcType: { type: "string" },
    },
    required: ["rcType"],
    additionalProperties: false,
  },
```

Hope this helps.